# Diferencia de Hora al obtener Hora del Servidor - PHP / Centos 6.9 / Apache

Tags: php, apache, centos6

Buenos días estoy intentando obtener la hora en PHP, pero a pesar de que (en teoria) tengo bien configurada la hora del servidor y la de php en el php.ini me trae una hora distinta a la configurada. A continuación las referencias:

De esta forma obtengo la hora y fecha en ***php***:

```
<?php


echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<br>";

echo date_default_timezone_get();

?>
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay que destacar que la hora correcta de Venezuela es la hora del servidor que es la siguiente(la obtengo con el comando `$ date`):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo ***php*** a pesar de estar configurado en la ruta de centos 6 `/etc/php.ini` de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me da una hora errada de 4 horas menos, 10:13:13 como se muestra en la imagen.

Mi pregunta sería que debo hacer para que en PHP se muestre la hora correcta de Venezuela. Pensaba que configurando la hora del servidor y el archivo php.ini era suficiente.

Nota: el servidor no es un VPS o un dedicado virtual, es un equipo físico ubicado en Caracas

Comment: ¿Lo comprobaste con `php_ini_loaded_file()`?

Comment: ¿Probaste con esto `date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');`? (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Relamente resolví el problema fue comentando el date.timezone en el php.ini, una locura. No comparto eso como solución porque no me parece que sea la correcta, pero así lo pude hacer funcionar.